# ITunes connect prerelease section show strange error

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect

I have just uploaded app on itunes connect for beta testing , but unfortunately prerelease tab is showing strange error ,
 [Check image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6nh0q9ocee99he/prerelease.tiff?dl=0)
I am stuck here so I cant invite any one for Beta testing any body please help

Comment: iTunes Connect has been having issues over the past few days. I'd suggest trying another browser/clearing cache/etc., but you may have to wait it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Joseph so tell me the plateform where do you discuss such problems , i think u will find lot of questions here which are real

Comment: @Ali twitter? Apple dev forums? It's definitely broken, anyway. We have to wait for Apple to fix it. The problem is real, it's just off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: It seems to be working again now.

Comment: I'm having issues too

Comment: yes its fine now it just ruined my day due to dead line :)

Comment: Just came across this problem on 19/3/2015, looks like it's a reoccurring issue or it might be that one of there servers or CDNs are not being updated.

Comment: Same. Doing a hard refresh didn't help as suggested below. I'll try other browsers and report back...

Comment: Nope, same across Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. See also, the Apple Forum: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6875976

Comment: Same here now. Even more odd, it keeps sending emails to internal testers notifying them of the new build - over and over again (maybe once for each time I tried refreshing, but who's counting). And I did not even go in to release that build for testing! Been doing this for the last hour. Refreshing did not help. Other browsers did not help. Uploading a new build did not help. How could they mess it up so badly?

Comment: Seems to be working for me this morning. Crisis averted.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the exact same thing and CMD+R worked for me! Just refresh the page and it should work.

You can also try a complete reload - CMD+SHIFT+R and that will re-request the page entirely.

Hope that's helpful in some way.

And yes the people who commented are correct, iTunes Connect has been having issues the last couple days and has even been down at times. You can check this site:

[Apple System Status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/)

Comment: Refreshing the page not working for me, unfortunately... I just get a loading spinner forever in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very technical solution, but I switched to a Private window and I was finally able to submit the same beta build.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted iTunesConnect support, having the same issue. Starting from the principle the these days the service has many issues of several types (issue of the day: TestFlight invitation were not sent to users), this is what the support suggested me to do:

"To resolve please clear your Safari Browsers cache and cookies. Please also toggle off and on the Test Flight Beta Testing switch. "